# Mootools code for success, failure and submit

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, mootools

Does **Mootools validation** have a similar process for

`Success`, `Failure` and `ajaxSubmitFile`?

```
 $("#rems").validationEngine({
                    ajaxSubmit: true,
                    ajaxSubmitFile: "database/agentpanel/reminder/makerem.php",
                    success : function() { 
                        $.get("database/agentpanel/reminder/loadrem.php", function(html) {
                        $("#rem-scroll").html(html);
                        alert("Reminder Set");
                        $('#rems').find("input[type=text], textarea").val("");
                        $('#rem_confirm').attr('checked', false);
                        });
                    }, 
                    failure : function() { alert("Fill in all the fields with Red Marks"); }
                });
```

I would like to be able to send the form without going to the next page, and also run an script on `success` and on `failure`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add event functions to Mootools *Form Request*.

Try this:

```
new Form.Request(myForm, myResult, {      
    onSend: function () {  // function to run on send
        alert('Will send now!');
    },
    onFailure: function (){//function to run if failure (fires after onComplete)
        alert('oops...!');
    },
    onComplete: function () {//function to run on send complete
        alert('Submited!');
    }, 
    onSuccess: function () {//function to run on success
        alert('Success!');
    },
    requestOptions: { //etc...
```

### Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qga6Y/)

**Worth to read:**

- Mootools blog on [**form request**](http://mootools.net/blog/2010/03/04/more-than-meets-the-eye/)
- Mootools [**docs**](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Forms/Form.Request) (Form.Request)